# Reading array for key in firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working with a Firebase Database where I am saving some player details as a list in value for a key. Following is my table structure:

[image: database structure screenshot]

Here in `EventPlayer` I have `eventID` as key and for `eventID` I am pushing Player details as `EventPlayer` model.

Now in my application I want to fetch the list of players for an `eventID` and display it in `RecyclerView`. I have tried various combinations but I am not able to get it. My code below:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserDataClass, EventPlayers.EventPlayerViewHolder> adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserDataClass, EventPlayers.EventPlayerViewHolder>(
            UserDataClass.class,
            R.layout.eventplayercard,
            EventPlayers.EventPlayerViewHolder.class,
            mref.child("EventPlayer").orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId)
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(EventPlayers.EventPlayerViewHolder viewHolder, final UserDataClass model, int position) {
            viewHolder.PlayerName.setText(model.getName());
            viewHolder.PlayerPosition.setText("Position: "+model.getPosition());
            viewHolder.PlayerFoot.setText("Foot: "+model.getPreffoot());
            viewHolder.PlayerKnownAs.setText("Event Date: "+model.getKnownas());
            final String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EventPlayers.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Remove Player");
                    alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove player?");

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            mref.child("EventRequest").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(key).setValue(null);
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### Edit

Code to push `EventPlayer`:

```
mref.child("EventPlayer").child(model.getEventID()).push().setValue(model);
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you are pushing the `EventPlayer` model onto the database? It looks like you have nested 2 pushes here.

Comment: there are two levels key values under `EventPlayer` node. make it one and it'll work

Comment: @Grimthorr I have updated my code please check Edit.

Comment: @RahulKumar I am pushing values for EventID key, The keys are generated when I push any value in firebase. Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: yes.. better way is to use the pojo to push the value so that these nesting won't be happening.

Comment: @RahulKumar I didn't understand, Do you have any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the 4th argument when your are creating an object of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` like this:

```
mref.child("EventPlayer").orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId)
```

with

```
mref.child("EventPlayer").child(model.getEventID()).orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId)
```

Comment: Change `model.getEventID()` with an actual event id. Does it work?

Comment: And? What happened?

Comment: All the properties of my model in populateViewHolder are null

Comment: I have used this: mref.child("EventPlayer").child(eventId).orderByChild("eventID").equalTo(eventId)

Comment: I think I found the mistake in my code, the name of properties are not matching in my app model and firebase model. I am correcting it and will check it then.

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 1):

From your current database structure, you are nesting 2 unique IDs under the `EventPlayer` node, so the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is likely retrieving data at the wrong level in the list.

You could adjust your push code to only use one level, by removing `child(model.getEventID())`:

```
mref.child("EventPlayer").push().setValue(model);
```

Or change your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to use the direct reference instead:

```
mref.child("EventPlayer").child(eventId);
```